# cannot convert char (*)[1000] to char **

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers, char

I created a char variable called str and I am trying to pass it into a function.  I keep on getting the `error cannot convert char (*)[1000] to char` **.  I know that for `cannot convert char to char *` you just use the `&` in front of the char, but I cannot figure out what to do in this case.  I searched stack and google and have had no luck. Any ideas?

```
 char str2[1000];
           strcpy(str2, "/home/" );
       strcat(str2, pw->pw_name );
        strcat(str2, "/Documents/test4.txt" );


    char bufTest[512];
    int link = GetSymbolicLinkTarget(&str2, bufTest, sizeof(bufTest));
```

Here is the function

```
int GetSymbolicLinkTarget(char *argv[], char *buf, size_t buf_size){
    int count = readlink(argv[1], buf, buf_size);
    if (count >= 0) {
        buf[count] = '\0';
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: "I created a char variable called `str` and I am trying to pass it into a function" - which function? The only functions you pass it to in your code are `strcpy()` and `strcat()`, neither of which can possibly give you that error message.

Comment: char *argv[] means a 2 dimensional array. You cannot convert into a char ** since both are different.

Comment: My idea would be: if you're going to write C++, write real C++. I'd start with: `std::string GetSymbolicLinkTarget(std::string const &input);`

Comment: @Aaron can you clarify whether you are allowed to change the function `GetSymbolicLinkTarget` ?

Comment: And, of course, do you *understand* `GetSymbolicLinkTarget` and what `argv[1]` means? (That it's the *second* entry in an array of strings.)

Comment: You way wish to clarify in the future whether you want a C++ answer or a C answer by only tagging one for a question. Replies in one language are often stylistically quite different from replies in the other as they are different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that the type of the first argument of `GetSymbolicLinkTarget` is `char* []` -- an array of pointers to char.

The type of `&str` is `char (*)[1000]` -- pointer to an array of 1000 char.

That's the mismatch the compiler is telling you about.

You can solve it using various ways:

**Option 1**

Change the type of the first argument of `GetSymbolicLinkTarget`.

```
int GetSymbolicLinkTarget(char *argv, char *buf, size_t buf_size){
```

This will require changes to how use `argv` in the function.

Then, you can just use:

```
GetSymbolicLinkTarget(str2, bufTest, sizeof(bufTest));
```

**Option 2**

Change the type of the first argument of `GetSymbolicLinkTarget`.

```
int GetSymbolicLinkTarget(char (*)argv[1000], char *buf, size_t buf_size){
```

This will also require changes to how use `argv` in the function.

Then, you can use:

```
GetSymbolicLinkTarget(&str2, bufTest, sizeof(bufTest));
```

**Option 3**

Use a wrapper variable in the calling function.

```
char* argv[2] = {0};
argv[1] = str2;
GetSymbolicLinkTarget(argv, bufTest, sizeof(bufTest));
```

This will not require any changes to how use `argv` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int GetSymbolicLinkTarget(char *argv[], char *buf, size_t buf_size){
    int count = readlink(argv[1], buf, buf_size);
    if (count >= 0) {
        buf[count] = '\0';
    }
    return count;
}
```

Weird. This function take an array of strings as its firsts parameter and then looks only at the second one. So let's create an array of strings where the string we want it to look at is the second one:

```
...
char* p[2];
p[1] = bufTest;
GetSymbolicLinkTarget(p, ...);
```

And there you go. It's quite bizarre that `GetSymbolicLinkTarget` works that way, but you have to call it with what it expects.

Comment: Or just change the function to accept a single `char *`, since it only uses one.

Comment: Or `const char *` so you don't piss off the callers when they can't pass perfectly sensible arguments.

Comment: You properly detect `GetSymbolicLinkTarget()` as 'weird' and then post a solution, that promotes this weirdness. `GetSymbolicLinkTarget()` should be definitely updated to accept parameters of proper types.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek It's always a delicate decision whether to answer the question the OP asked or the question they should have asked.

Comment: What should I be asking?

Comment: @Aaron: How to write the prototype for `GetSymbolicLinkTarget()` so that it matches what the function actually needs.

Comment: @Aaron It's hard to be completely sure. Did you write `GetSymbolicLinkTarget`? Do you understand it? If you wrote it, your question should be about how to write such a function sanely. If you don't understand it, your question should be about understanding it.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek it seems likely that this function was written by someone else, e.g. maybe it's part of some third party library and OP has to call it unaltered (or would prefer to call it unaltered unless there is no other option)

Comment: I wrote GetSymbolicLinkTarget to be able to use readlink which is a c Linux function call.

Comment: @Aaron Why did you write it to look only at the second entry in `argv`? That seems like a baffling choice.

Comment: @Aaron: Why did you write it to look like it accepts the second argument to `main()`, when that's not what you pass it? Just change `GetSymbolicLinkTarget()` and your problem is solved. Even if you did want to pass command line arguments, just pass it `&argv[1]` instead of `argv`, since your function should not depend upon where its data comes from.

Comment: I found some code with an example for readlink.  I wrote a small program and got the result I needed.  I am having trouble writing the unit test for it

Comment: In main I pass in the argument /home/aakatz//Documents/test4.txt.  I am using eclipse